# Can anyone tell me why am having Null for the object Staff and how can I fix it

Tags: inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism

I have a class called main, and Staff that inherits from Person2

1) I should create an ArrayList that holds objects of type Staff

2) Then create Staff object using Person2 class and insert it in the list

3) Make user enter data for staff object then print it

I have a problem that when I run my main, I get Null values for what the user entered for object Staff which means there is something wrong I did

Main file

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Staff>list=new ArrayList<Staff>();

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    list.add(new Staff());
    list.add(new Staff("Marry", 23,500));

    System.out.println("Enter name");
    String name=in.next();

    System.out.println("Enter age");
    int age=in.nextInt();

    list.get(0).setName(name);
    list.get(0).setAge(age);

    Person2 c = new Staff(); 
    list.add((Staff) c); 
    System.out.println("Enter name");
    String name=in.next();

    System.out.println("Enter age");
    int age=in.nextInt();

    // Then what should I write here to not get null results for the object Staff


    for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
        System.out.println(list.get(i));

}

}
```

Person file

```
public class Person2 {

private String name;
private int age;
private String contactNumber;


public Person2()
{
    System.out.println(" Constructing default Person");

}

 Person2 ( String n, int a )
 { 
     System.out.println(" Constructing non-default Person");
     name = n;
     age = a;


 }

 public void setName( String name)
 {
     this.name = name;
 }

 public String getName()
 {
     return name;
 }

 public void setAge( int age)
 {
     this.age = age;
 }

 public int getAge()
 {
     return age;
 }


 public String toString()
 {
     return "Name : " +getName()
             +"\nAge :" +getAge()

 }
 }
```

Staff file

```
public class Staff extends Person2{

private double salary;

public Staff()
{
    System.out.println("Constructing default Staff ");
}

public Staff( String name, int age, double salary)
{
    super(name, age);
    System.out.println("Constructing non-default Staff ");
    this.salary = salary;
}

public void setSalary( double salary)
{
    this.salary = salary;
}

public double getSalary()
{
    return salary;
}

    public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() +"\nSalary : " +getSalary();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some serious mistakes in your main method. Lists are not supposed to be used like that.

I have provided a possible fix for the application. Took an assumption that you need to read details of 5 staff employees.

Not provided the salary part. You may add it if you wish

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Staff>list=new ArrayList<Staff>();

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i ++) {
        Staff staff = new Staff();
        System.out.println("Enter name");
        String name=in.next();

        System.out.println("Enter age");
        int age=in.nextInt();

        staff.setAge(age);
        staff.setName(name);

        list.add(staff);
    }

    for (Staff staff : list) {
        System.out.println(staff.toString());
    }
}

}
```

I think this will do what you wish.